# Protractor - How to check if object is contained in another object?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have two objects:

```
let obj1 = {
   FirstName: "John",
   LastName: "Doe",
   age: 20,
   color: "Purple"
}

let obj2 = {
   FirstName: "John",
   LastName: "Doe",
   color: "Purple
}
```

As you can see, I got two almost similar 2 objects.
The only difference is that the second object doesn't have "age" property in it.
I want to compare between them and check if the second object is "contained" in the first one.
I tried

```
expect(obj1).toContain(obj2);
```

It doesn't work.
Is that even possible option?

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are the same you can use Equatable, for example:

```
struct Person: Equatable {
var name: String?
var color: UIColor?
var LastName: String?
}




var person1 =  Person()
person1.name = "roei"
person1.LastName = "b"
person1.color = .blue



var person2 =  Person()
person2.name = "roei"
person2.LastName = "b"
person2.color = .blue


 if person1 == person2 {
    print("good")
}
```

it will print good